# How to retrieve image form database to a Label when " Treeview focus"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

When I click in treeview I can retrieve data to the Entry Box but I CAN NOT retrieve the image, which is already saved in database in advance, to the its label . The image Label defined as "label_photo" and a variable as "self.var_S_Photo".

Your help is appreciated

Here is the Method

```
def get_date(ev):
            r=self.StudentTable.focus()
            content=self.StudentTable.item(r)
            row=content["values"]
            self.var_S_Roll_No.set(row[0])
            self.var_S_Name.set(row[1])
            self.var_S_Dob.set(row[2])
            self.var_S_Gender.set(row[3])
            self.var_S_Photo.set(row[4])
```

Comment: _"I CAN NOT retrieve the image,"_ - why can't you? What happens when you try?

Comment: When I click on the treeview row the data appear on their Entry boxes but not the image. I want the image appear with its own Entry data whenever I click in treeview row.

Comment: tkinter `Variable` is not used for image.  You need to use `label_photo.config(image=...)` to update the image of the label.  Note that the value assigned to `image` option should be an instance of `tkinter.PhotoImage()` or `ImageTk.PhotoImage()` (from pillow module).

Comment: @acw1668 As you can see the Method I already mentioned above what should I do ? Would you please write the code for me since I am still beginner . Your help is appreciated .

Comment: What is the content of `row[4]`? A string? If it is a string, how do you expect it to be displayed as image?

Comment: @acw1668 I know `row[4]` not correct I just want to try or find a way to work. So what should I do as you understand me . Thank you .

Comment: What I understand, `row` are the values from a `Treeview` record which should contain strings only.  So where is the image?

Comment: @acw1668  The Method that mentioned above can help me whenever I click on single treeview row record show up back this record on their Entry Boxes in case if you want to update it , along with this record there is a picture for each single one, the record data showed up good but not with its picture . I Know now that `row[4]` was incorrect; therefore, could you tell how I can fix this ? what to add, delete or edit ?? Thank you .

Comment: When you insert the image into the treeview, you need to save the reference of the image. Suggest to use a dictionary and use the "roll_no" as the key to store the reference of the image.  Then when you select a row in the treeview, you can get the image from the dictionary using the "roll_no".